# How can I align two textviews where one of them has padding using constraint layout?

Tags: android, textview, android-constraintlayout

I would like to achieve the following layout

[image]

The bottom layover `TextView` has a rounded rectangle drawable as a background. I would like to align the text inside the `TextView` with the top text. Currently what happens is that the rounded edges align with the text and not the actual text.
Any ideas on how to implement this with `ConstraintLayout`? I tried setting `layout_constraintStart_toStartOf` the text above and set negative padding but I guess constraints have priority here and ignores the padding.

Here is the full xml layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/trip_type_icon"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:tint="@color/oslo_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/trip_month"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/trip_date"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_car_pickup" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@color/oslo_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/trip_type_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trip_date"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/shark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/trip_month"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/trip_type_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trip_month"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/emperor"
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/trip_timeline_subtitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/trip_type_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/trip_date"
        tools:text="Sep" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trip_timeline_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/shark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/navigate_arrow"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/trip_date"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="PVG -> PEK" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trip_timeline_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:textColor="@color/emperor"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/trip_timeline_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/trip_date"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/trip_timeline_title"
        tools:text="2:10pm - 4:45pm" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/navigate_arrow"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/trip_timeline_subtitle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/trip_timeline_title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/trip_timeline_title"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_right_vector" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trip_timeline_flight_layover"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_radius_12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/emperor"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/navigate_arrow"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/trip_timeline_subtitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/trip_timeline_subtitle"
        tools:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_radius_12dp"
        tools:text="2h 25m Layover at PEK"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Rounded rectangle drawable `rounded_rectangle_radius_12dp`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:tint="@color/porcelain">
    <corners android:radius="12dp" />
    <padding android:left="12dp"
        android:right="12dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Can you please post the layout xml file so that we can copy it in our own development IDE and test it there? Please add/remove the styles or drawables as well so that we can compile the layout without an error.

Comment: @ReazMurshed done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define padding inside your `trip_timeline_flight_layover` `TextView` instead of your drawable:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trip_timeline_flight_layover"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_radius_12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/emperor"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/navigate_arrow"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/trip_timeline_subtitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/trip_timeline_subtitle"
        tools:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_radius_12dp"
        tools:text="2h 25m Layover at PEK"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
```

And then set `layout_marginStart` of `trip_timeline_title` equal to the padding of your ``` layover``TextView ```, in this case, `12dp`.

**EDIT:**

I actually don't think you have to define padding inside your `TextView`, just making margin of your title equal to the side padding should work.